# Is this code no longer viable in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm just starting out as a junior dev, but what I know is pretty basic(I was honest with this and the company was ok with it). I was told to learn as much as I possibly could about php currently and to figure out some pimcore codes on my own.

Anyway, I'm currently taking a Laravel tutorial from udemy and the instructor typed this line of code in routes, as there's no longer a single route file anymore in laravel 5, I went and put this in /route/web.php

```
Route::get('/admin/posts/a', array('as'=>'admin.home'), function(){
    $url=route('admin.home');
    return "this url is". $url;
});
```

It gave me a ReflectionException error on the page when I went to that url, is this code no longer viable in Laravel 5? if so, how would I go about adapting it?

Comment: What version of laravel are you using? using 'as' array key to define route name is still usable till Laravel 5.2

Comment: @catcon i'm using version 5.8

Comment: `Route('/admin/post/a', function() {...})->name('admin.home');` is how you should name a route on Laravel 5.8

Comment: Since you are beginner, I recommend that either use the laravel version that match with the tutorial and learn the basic first, or find another tutorial that use laravel 5.8. Don't waste your time on debugging just because of the version mismatch.

Comment: @catcon thank you, i'll just find another tutorial for 5.8, since that's the latest version. Learning 5.2 would be useless anyway if afterwards i wouldn't be able to use it anywhere.